# Removing Files From a Path Older Than 60 Days Old Fails

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that removes log files older than 60 days.  It gets to a particular file and fails saying the file doesn't exist.  The funny thing is the code is not pointing to a particular file but the folder. I changed the path to not reveal anything about my environment.  Sample below.  Any ideas?

```
clear-Host
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

$Path = 'C:\Windows\Temp'
Get-ChildItem  $Path | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item
```

Comment: You  are excluding folders in your Where-Object clause: -not $_.PSIsContainer.

Comment: "It gets to a particular file and fails saying the file doesn't exist" - is there anything _different_ about this file compared to the rest? Attributes set, weird characters in the name, is it an actual file and not a link/junction? There's nothing immediately wrong about your script.

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Force`

Comment: `$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date` to compare as of midnight and `Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -File -Force`. Now you can remove `-not $_.PSIsContainer`. Also, why are you testing for both `CreationTime` AND `LastWriteTime` ? Just LastWriteTime would suffice. For safety, add switch `-WhatIf` to the `Remove-Item` so you can first determine the correct files would be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to look at:

**Is it safe to just nuke the %tempdir%?**

Nowadays most apps will write to files in %localAppdata%\Temp which is in the user profile, so it's mostly Windows OS services using \Temp, which makes the `C:\Windows\Temp` path sort of a special directory.  Sometimes processes might be running that have a lock on a file in that directory, and if you delete them, things can go poorly for the process.  Those errors tend to look like this:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\temp\stack\2.txt: 
   The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\stack\2.txt' because 
   it is being used by another process.
```

However, these are *not terminating errors*, which means the rest of the directory will get cleaned out.  So if you don't care about the error, you could just append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Remove-Item` cmdlet and consider the ticket done.

**Your code isn't just removing log files though**.

You mentioned that you want to delete only log files.  In that case, you might want to append a file filter to only remove logs because today your code is going to nuke the whole directory.  Adding a filter is really easy, it would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log | Where {#....
```